# How can i prevent RIA service change tracking for certain fields?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, entity-framework-4, silverlight-3.0, wcf-ria-services

How can i prevent RIA service change tracking on certain properties. I have a partial class and i want that RIA service should not track changes to it. How can i do that?

Currently if i see in generated code, i can methods like OnXXXChanging() nad OnXXXChanged() etc etc. I want these should not be generated for my custom properties.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Any chance you could just move the partial to the client?

Comment: It won't help because I am populating those fields on server (but they are not part of database model).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stop RIA Services tracking (or even generating) a property, just add the `[Exclude]` attribute to the property (either in the `.shared.cs` or in a metadata class.

If you then add a `[DataMember]` attribute, WCF will still serialize/deserialize it, but RIA Services won't care about it.